# TabStrip background color different from regular colors on iPhone

Tags: ios, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am using the color `rgb(0, 89, 79)` as one of the primary colors for my NativeScript Angular app. On an iPhone I noticed that when that color is used in the ActionBar and in a TabStrip it is a fair bit lighter than when it is used on a button or just as a background color anywhere else in the app. I found [this](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/how-to-match-a-nativescript-actionbar-s-color-on-ios) blog post explaining that I could use `flat="true"` on the ActionBar to remove the iOS styling that was lightening the background color of the ActionBar.

I tried the same thing on the TabStrip but it has no effect. Does anyone know of a way to remove whatever styling apple applies to the TabStrip?

Comment: `flat` is not a valid property on `TabStrip`, set `translucent` to `false` on the native tabBar - https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/e2e/ui-tests-app/app/action-bar/flat-tab-opaque-bar-page.ts

Comment: The only problem with that is I am not using a TabView. I followed the instructions [here](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/implementing-a-login-for-nativescript-apps-with-tab-based-navigation) to set the app up using multiple page router outlets.

Comment: They all internally use the same native component, so it should work.

Comment: Good to know. I will give it a try and update with my findings. Thanks.

Comment: I tried adding that but I think I might be missing something. In my project I have a "tabs" that contains tabs.module.ts, tabs.component.html, tabs.component.ts, tabs.component.css, and flat-tabs.ts. In tabs.component.html I have 
    <BottomNavigation class="ns-light" loaded="onLoaded">
    <TabStrip>...</TabStrip>
    <TabContentItem> ... </TabContentItem>
    </BottomNaviagtion>

and in tabs.component I added 
    import { onLoaded } from "./flat-tabs"
But it doesn't make any difference. Can you tell me what I am missing?

Comment: I figured it out. I moved the onLoaded function to tabs.component.ts and had to make sure to use proper syntax in the BottomNavigation tag: <BottomNavigation (loaded)="onLoaded($event)">.