# NativeScript last element in scrollview partially hidden by Bottom Navigation

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am using tabbed navigation for my nativescript app. I have a playground sample here https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=WKlZDF&v=6

On the second tab, I have a list of tasks that is longer than most screens can display so it is wrapped in a `<ScrollView>`. The scrolling works as expected except when you get to the bottom. The final element is partially hidden by the `<BottomNavigation>`. If you drag up on the screen you can see the rest of the element but the second you release the screen it slides back down behind the `<BottomNavigation>`.

You can see what I am talking about in the playground or in the screenshot below. Does anyone know how to correct this? I thought about just adding a bunch of padding at the bottom but that seems super hackey.

[image]

Comment: That's because you have set `translucent` to `false` on TabBar. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979281/ios-7-tabbar-translucent-issue

Comment: @Manoj, I set translucent to false to get the TabBar color to match the ActionBar per your recommendation when I asked this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61372212/tabstrip-background-color-different-from-regular-colors-on-iphone) question. I tried removing the translucent = false and the last element is no longer hidden but the colors no longer match. Is there not a way to have the ActionBar and TabBar colors match while also having the last element visible?

Comment: Yes, there are various solutions discussed in the thread I linked above. Did you check those?

Comment: @Manoj, My bad. I did not read far enough.